# Detection Rate vs False Positives Per Image Curve

Tags: matlab, computer-vision

I have been trying to understand how I can extract a *Detection Rate vs FPPI* curve as shown below, obtained from *Ref1*.

[image]

In this paper they analyze their system before (RAW detector) and after applying tracking by showing the graph above. I would like to do the same for a tracking by detection approach (MATLAB) that I've used, however I am currently stuck on how this can be done. As a sidenote I will be evaluating my system over a set of image sequences *visually*. Can someone please offer some advice on how I can generate this curve please? Your help is much appreciated.

Ref1: [Detecting People Looking at Each Other in Videos](https://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/publications/2014/Marin14/marin14.pdf)

Comment: Is the question how to generate the graph in matlab given measurements or is it how to automate the capture of the measurements and then to generate the graph ?

Comment: No I do not need to automate it since I can get the values visually but I wish to understand how I can produce this curve on MATLAB if you please :). I will edit the question to make it more clear.

Comment: I presume you don't have an issue with the concept of plotting things in MATLAB, so is the issue that you don't understand how to calculate those values? Did you read this part of the paper, and the paper it references? *Following the standard PASCAL VOC protocol (Everingham et al. 2010), we count a detection as correct if the intersection-over-union with any ground-truth bounding-box exceeds 0.5.*

Comment: Yes @nkjt I read the VOC protocol and knew that DR is calculated as said so. However, maybe to be more precise the tracker I implemented all it does is suppresses some false positives (extracted from the detector); and I wish to depict in a graphical manner how the accuracy increases pre-applying my tracker and after applying the tracker as in this paper. Now extracted the tracker accuracy and false alarm rate visually over a set of images sequences. However, I do not know how this can be placed in a graph we are discussing.

Comment: Sorry, still really don't get where you're stuck. If you've calculated the appropriate numbers, surely all you need to do is `plot` them? You should have a set of numbers from the detector without tracker (showing that as you increase sensitivity DR rises but FPPI also rises), and another set with the tracker (showing for the same DR you reduce the FPPI).  Is that not what you've calculated?

Comment: I think I got it know. No I think we did not communicate well. What I extracted is simply overall detection rate and number of false positives for the whole image sequence (footage). So, till now I only have the 2 values: 1). Overall Detection rate 2). False Positive rate. However, now if I understood you correctly I have to vary the detector's sensitivity so as to extract the points on the curve? I am using HOG+SVM for my detector. So in my case what do you think should be varied so as to extract such a curve please?

Comment: This looks very much like an [ROC curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic) to me. Typically to plot an ROC curve, you vary the threshold of your classifier. Most SVM's default to >0 scores are positives, <0 are negatives.  Choose a score threshold for the SVM such that you get a certain false positive rate. For example, choose a threshold like >0.5 to be positive examples such that FP = 10%. The threshold should also give you a detection rate (DR). (FP, DR) is your first datapoint. To make the curve, continue to vary the threshold.

Comment: Thank you very much Cecilia. This is what I was expecting as an answer. I wish that you voluntarily place it as an answer so that I will accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let me quotate from: [Articulated Part-based Model for Joint Object Detection and Pose Estimation](http://cvgl.stanford.edu/papers/sun_iccv11_iccv_supp_camera.pdf):

> When plotting the recall v.s. FPPI curves, we first collect all the
>   candidate object instances (including object bounding boxes and part
>   locations), then we sort the candidate instances in a descend order
>   according to the overall matching score (Eq.[4] in the main paper).
>   Finally, we calculate the recalls and FPPIs using different thresholds
>   of the matching score to generate the curves.

**Eq.4** can be any bounded non-negative scoring function

Up to my humble understanding of object detection, this is used widely in many papers that use [ETHZ Shape Classes](http://www.vision.ee.ethz.ch/datasets/index.en.html) for instance, and for this dataset the performance is reported at 0.4 FPPI in many papers.

Answer (score 0):

The following was generated from Matlab's interactive plot editor. You can call it with your X and Y series, X and Y should be the same length. I've added some annotations to explain what it's doing if not immediately obvious

function createfigure(NX1, X1, NY1, Y1)
    %CREATEFIGURE(X1,Y1)
    %  NX1:  name of x data for legend
    %  NY1:  name of y data for legend
    %  X1:  vector of x data
    %  Y1:  vector of y data

```
% Create figure
figure1 = figure('XVisual','');

% Create axes
axes1 = axes('Parent',figure1,...
    'YTick',[0 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1 ],... % Tick marks on Y axis ...
    'YGrid','on',...       % Enable the horizontal grid lines
    'XTick',[0 0.25 0.5 0.75 1 1.25 1.5],... % Tick marks for X axis
    'XGrid','on');         % Enable vertical grid lines

    box(axes1,'on');
    hold(axes1,'all');

% Create plot - line colour is [r g b] so this is green
plot(X1,Y1,'Color',[0 1 0]);

% Create title
title('Upper Body Detection and tracking performance');

% Create legend
legend( NX1, NY1, 'East' );
```